# Get Cursor Control for Disabled Control

Tags: java, swt

I want to get the control the mouse hovers over which normally is done by `Display#getCursorControl`. However when one control in the hierarchy is disabled, this method doesn't work any longer:

**Example:**

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setSize(400, 300);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

    final Label mouseControl = new Label(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    mouseControl.setLayoutData(GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().span(2, 1).grab(true, true).create());
    display.addFilter(SWT.MouseMove,
            e -> mouseControl.setText("" + e.display.getCursorControl()));

    final Group enabledGroup = new Group(shell, SWT.NONE);
    enabledGroup.setLayoutData(GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, true).create());
    enabledGroup.setText("Enabled Group");
    createControls(enabledGroup);

    final Group disabledGroup = new Group(shell, SWT.NONE);
    disabledGroup.setLayoutData(GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, true).create());
    disabledGroup.setText("Disabled Group");
    disabledGroup.setEnabled(false);
    createControls(disabledGroup);

    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}

private static void createControls(Composite parent) {
    parent.setLayout(new GridLayout());

    final Label label = new Label(parent, SWT.NONE);
    label.setText("Label");

    final Text text = new Text(parent, SWT.BORDER);
    text.setText("Text");
}
```

Hold the mouse over the left label and then over the right one. The control is only displayed for an enabled parent, else the shell is displayed.

How do I get the control below the mouse pointer? Do I have to implement this functionality myself? Are there any methods that can help me or do I have to calculate the bounds of each control inside the tree and check if it is on the mouse position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see anything in `Display` that would help.

The following will search the children of a `Shell` for a control containing the cursor and works with disabled controls:

```java
static Control findCursorinShellChildren(final Shell shell)
{
  return findLocationInCompositeChildren(shell, shell.getDisplay().getCursorLocation());
}


static Control findLocationInCompositeChildren(final Composite composite, final Point displayLoc)
{
  final var compositeRelativeLoc = composite.toControl(displayLoc);

  for (final var child : composite.getChildren())
   {
     if (child.getBounds().contains(compositeRelativeLoc))
      {
        if (child instanceof Composite)
         {
           final var containedControl = findLocationInCompositeChildren((Composite)child, displayLoc);
           return containedControl != null ? containedControl : child;
         }

        return child;
      }
   }

  return null;
}
```

I imagine this is going to be significantly slower than `Display.getCursorControl`